# How do I change terminal font on Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: fonts, mate, ubuntu-mate

How do I change terminal font on Ubuntu MATE ?

It seems like there are two terminals in MATE. One is "MATE Terminal" which has nice readable font and other is something that is used when I launch app created in GUI menu

[image]

How do I change it ?

Screenshot of terminal I want to change

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the other Terminal?

Comment: Oh to! I said the other ugly one!

Comment: @Anwar Added as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is a bug in GLib, maintained by gnome developers. They have hard-coded a set of terminals emulator to try for these launchers and in that list, `mate-terminal` is not included. Even `konsole`, `xfce4-terminal` is also excluded.

Here is the bug report in github https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/issues/57

Read the summary made by MoonSweep

> So, to summarize:
>
> Contrary to what was said at the beginning of this thread, this is not a Mint-only issue, and this has nothing to do with the TERM variable. This is a known bug from GLib which has a hard-coded set of terminals to try and launch, and several of them are missing from this list (not only mate-terminal, but xfce-terminal or konsole for example are also missing).
>
> Knowing how the Gnome guys are oblivious to anything outside of Gnome, I think it's no use to ask them to fix this issue in GLib, that's why I made a patch handling mate-terminal and posted it in the Debian BTS, then when mate-terminal's package started to provide a wrapper compatible with xterm, I updated the patch to handle x-terminal-emulator (which is a Debian alternative for all terminal emulators compatible with xterm), thus allowing GLib in Debian (and derivatives) to handle not only mate-terminal but all terminals which can be set as this alternative.

### What can you do?

From My test, I saw that if you have `gnome-terminal` installed, it will first try that one. So, to avoid ugly `xterm`, you can install `gnome-terminal` which is very similar to mate-terminal and included in default Ubuntu Unity.

To install, use this command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

For me, it fixed the issue. Try it. Hope it will work for you too!

Comment: Another way to _avoid ugly xterm_ is to execute the following in terminal emulator to change `xterm` font: `xterm -fa "Noto Mono" -fs 14 -geometry 140x30+0 &`. If it works, then you can source it in a shell script: `. xterm_noto.sh` from the cwd.